# Parse string to f64 and a i64

Tags: parsing, numbers, rust

I can't seem to dig up anything on the official docs. I can see that there are multiple old ways of doing this (`int::parse_bytes` and `f32::from_string`) but both of these are deprecated. What is the way this is performed in 1.0?

Answer (score 13):

```
 &str.parse::< "type" >().unwrap() -> "type"
```